# Is there an algorithm/procedure to return a color(s) X that is some distance value K from color Y? Color(s) at a boundary from an origin color

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, colors

I am basically looking to see if it is possible to return which color(s) are some distance value K from a given color. The distance is in terms of deltaE. So far what I have found on the internet is that it is possible to detect how far away two given colors are and get the deltaE value. I am trying to determine the other side of this coin now. Which color(s) are a fixed distance away from the origin color.

Looking at the CIE94 Delta E equation, Math wise I am not sure, because the equation would need to solve for three unknown values "l" "a" and "b"....

Comment: It's a 3D space, so there's an infinite number of colors on the surface of a sphere at that radius. You're going to have to narrow down your criteria.

Comment: @MarkRansom How is that possible? There are (256)^3 possible color values in the rgb model. Maybe I need to specify I am talking about RGB?

Comment: You're working in Lab space which isn't discrete. There are an infinite number of colors that will map to each of those 256^3 RGB colors.

Comment: @MarkRansom Let me refine my question then, the reason for this is I am basically trying to figure out a way to take a set of colors, and reduce that set of colors to colors that contrast each other (distance between them >= K). Is there anyway to do this in one pass? Every algorithm I come up with is order N^2

I tried reducing the problem to maybe the famous problem of finding all pairs in an array that sum to K. Reducing it to this problem has not worked so far.

In general not sure if this problem is solvable in the class of N (linear).